Replacing throw(...) with noexcept(...) - ABI safe across language standards?
Suppose I'm using a library that has a declaration like this in its header:
#if __cplusplus >= 201703L
// C++17 or newer
    #define _NOTHROW noexcept(true)
    #define _THROWS(x) noexcept(false)
#else
    #define _NOTHROW throw()
    #define _THROWS(x) throw(x)
#endif

And then uses the above macros on its function declarations in its .h file, and in its function definitions in its .cpp file.
Is it safe, using GCC or Clang, to compile this library for C++11, and then include its header in a application being compiled for C++17 and (statically) link them? I know that in general with GCC and Clang it's safe to link between different C++ standards if you compile them both with the exact same compiler version, but I was wondering if there's an issue with the fact that when the library was compiled (for C++11) the functions were marked throw() and throw(some_exception_type), but then when the main application was being compiled (for C++17) it saw declarations marked with noexcept(true) and noexcept(false) instead.

It is not.
Consider the following declarations in one of the library's headers:
void f() _NOTHROW;
void g(decltype(&f));

On the Linux ABI, g's mangled name in C++11 is _Z1gPFvvE and in C++17 it is _Z1gPDoFvvE. (see here).
Therefore, if g is defined in one of the library's sources, compiled as C++11, the symbol defined will be _Z1gPFvvE. If g is called by one of the application functions, compiled as C++17, it will attempt to call _Z1gPDoFvvE and it will fail to link.
Ultimately, this is because noexcept is part of the typesystem and therefore must be represented in certain symbols.

Ah right, I didn't think about externally-visible symbols that take function pointers as arguments. I believe GCC has a warning for this enabled with -Wall, so at least we should be able to catch these with -Werror. I imagine that in practice it's unlikely to come up. Certainly something to audit

This would be an issue even if we declared void f() noexcept without any macro, right? Since in C++11 noexcept was not part of the function type, but in C++17 it is

Correct. This really boils down to noexcept is part of the type starting in C++17. Therefore, it affects function type, function pointer assignability, mangling some uses, etc.

With a bit of work you can write trampolines for this case

@Yakk-AdamNevraumont I'd be curious to know if you're referring to anything in particular. IME, the traditional approach to maintaining ABI compatible interfaces is essentially writing a bunch of extern "C" "trampolines"... i.e. expose an extern "C" interface. Is your comment just suggestive of that direction?

@JeffGarrett I'm saying you can export something with the right mangled name from your library that an earlier version of C++ could consume, as well as one that a later version of C++ would consume, and that one could call the other.
